# Markdown borks URLs with port numbers

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, markdown

If you link to a URL with a port number, Markdown will eagerly percent-encode the colon the separates the host name from the port number. See [this test message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6639235#6639235). The chat message I typed in looks like this:

```
[Test case for bug report about Morkdown](http://example.com:80/)
```

But the generated HTML (as shown by Chrome's DOM inspector) looks like this:

```
 <a href="http://example.com%3A80/" rel="nofollow">Test case for bug report about Morkdown</a>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the percent-encoding, just "example.com" as the link. You should consider including a screenshot too.

Comment: Click it, or look at it in the DOM. Thanks for the edit @Caleb.

Comment: "click it" is browser-specific; even with the %-encoding, it works ok in Chrome; not an intentional behavior, though

Comment: @MarcGravell: Same issue here, percent encoded seems to work fine in Chrome. (And even custom links specified as port 80 are being stripped by Chrome to be just the domain when followed). I guess the question is: is percent encoding compliant with whatever protocol spec it needs to be in this case?

Comment: @Marc ah, ok. FWIW, I am using Firefox, which does not fix it.

Comment: @Caleb if I had to guess, I'll say "not in that location". Intriguing question, though.

Comment: For info, the current behavior is linked to [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69879/comment-nofollow-exploit), and links like `[link text](http://x.y#http://a.b)` - I'm trying to see if I can tweak the handling of ports in the outer url, though

Comment: @Marc oh well, that bug teases me with waffles. Now I'm hungry.

Comment: @MarcGravell: The relevant [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) makes it relevantly clear (as clear as RFC's generally are) that the colon is used as a component separator and that percent encoding should be applied to each component separately when you don't want the characters to be interpreted as possible component delimiters or other special functions. Applying the encoding to a multi-component bit and thus encoding the delimiter is pretty clearly wrong.

Comment: @Caleb heh; if you want uncertainty, ask each browser vendor whether the "+" in a "mailto" address needs escaping, i.e. `mailto:marc+spam@someemail.com`; there is **no** version that works on all browsers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All fixed for future usage. Existing links may show using the old handling, and I don't propose refreshing them all.