# Adding links to Google webfont sites is broken

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

this [link](http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Lato) is broken when adding it through clicking **Hyperlink** icon in the edit form.

If I instead paste the link directly as is, then it's working fine, like this:

http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Lato

As **Oded** user noted in a comment, the bug seems to be the *markdown renderer encodes : on the URL when it shouldn't* .

So, do you know if StackOverflow engine uses some open source library to format the markdown code?

so I can take a peek at fixing the bug (I love fixing the bugs I hit myself)..

Comment: How do you mean broken? What happens? Do you mean it looses the fragment portion?

Comment: Click and follow both links, they don't go to the same site, yet I pasted the same link on both forms (through clicking icon and pasting directly in the form). The right site is the one you get when clicking the long texted link, so adding the link through the icon is broken, the link adress is mangled, I think it gets confused with the `#` or `:` characters present in the query string.

Comment: If you need further clarification for this bug then let me know.

Comment: In short, the markdown renderer encodes `:` on the URL when it shouldn't.

Comment: Correct, that's seem to be the root cause.

Comment: Partially related: [Markdown borks URLs with port numbers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158286) (although I'm not sure that the concerns with `:` in MarkdownMini are the same as the ones in normal Markdown, I suppose it's more likely to avoid `[#]:` conflicts)

Comment: Not directly related, but for linking purposes: [Hyperlink button breaks some URLs when automatically undoing URL encoding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153278)